# Unable to connect Sql server and hive from presto

Tags: sql-server, hive, presto, presto-jdbc

My presto is up and running having following issue on connectors.
i have installed presto in root, my hive is in "hadoop" user and my "sql" is in another user

And i am getting
Java.net.connectexception: Failed to  connect /127.0.0.1:8090 for sql

And timeout for hive

> sql.properties:
> connector.name=sqlserver
> connection-url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433 connection-user=SA
> connection-password=xxxxxx

Comment: Could you please provide more details? How you try to launch the web interface? When you have the exception?

Comment: Which Presto version are you running and what problems are you seeing?

Comment: Also, since you mention 3 different problems, this looks like a troubleshooting more than a SO question. If you feel the same, you can move this to `#troubleshooting` on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Comment: i have edited the question.